Email Customization - Can't get user_activationo_key
I hope someone can help or had the same problem, because I don't know how to get to a solution.
I am trying to customize the registration email of new users, where the password set link is. For the whole customization, I use a "template" from codewp. My problem is that i can't get the user_activation_key into the url and I don't know why. I tried several things but now I don't know what to do anymore.
When I leave it as it is in the template, I get the username but not the key.
$message .= "<a $link_style href='" . network_site_url( "change-password/?wpforo=resetpassword&rp_key=". rawurlencode( $user->user_activation_key ), 'key'  . " &login=" . rawurlencode( $user->user_login ), 'login' ) . "'>" . __( 'Set Your Password' ) . "</a>";
Here the URL i get from this:

Then I tried doing it the same way for the password, as they did for the login in the code:
$message .= "<a $link_style href='" . network_site_url( "change-password/?wpforo=resetpassword&rp_key=rp&key=$user->user_activation_key&login=" . rawurlencode( $user->user_login ), 'login' ) . "'>" . __( 'Set Your Password' ) . "</a>";
Here, I got nothing back.

I am very new to "coding" so there's probably some easy fix but I can't find a solution.
Thank a lot in advance!
Markus
The Function in wpforo:

function wpforo_lostpassword_url( $redirect_to = null ) {
if( wpforo_setting( 'authorization', 'lost_password_url' ) ) {
$lostpassword_url = trim( (string) get_bloginfo( 'url' ), '/' ) . '/' . ltrim( (string) wpforo_setting( 'authorization', 'lost_password_url' ), '/' );
} else {
if( wpforo_setting( 'authorization', 'use_our_lostpassword_url' ) ) {
$lostpassword_url = wpforo_url( wpforo_get_redirect_to_url_path( $redirect_to ), 'lostpassword' );
} else {
if( is_null( $redirect_to ) ) $redirect_to = wpforo_get_redirect_to();
$lostpassword_url = wp_lostpassword_url( $redirect_to );
}
}
$lostpassword_url = apply_filters( 'wpforo_lostpassword_url', $lostpassword_url );
return esc_url_raw( $lostpassword_url );
}


Can you post text please and not images? You can use code formatting (backticks) or block quotes ( > ) to make it stand out.

Sorry, didn't know how to do it properly. Should be right now.

I have no idea how this plays with wpForo, but in the standard reset flow rp_key is extracted from the password reset cookie. See wp-login.php:
$rp_cookie = 'wp-resetpass-' . COOKIEHASH;
if ( isset( $_COOKIE[ $rp_cookie ] ) && 0 < strpos( $_COOKIE[ $rp_cookie ], ':' ) ) {
    list( $rp_login, $rp_key ) = explode( ':', wp_unslash( $_COOKIE[ $rp_cookie ] ), 2 );

You'd have to look at the wpForo code or ask them for help / documentation if they do something different.

How can I implement this into the php snippet? In wpforo, I found the function I added to the end of my question. But why is the user_login working and the activation key not?
Can I paste the link of the website I got the php snippet from?
Regards
Markus

Also is it possible, that the user_activation_key is protected? Because I tried switching both the login and the key on how they get extracted from the database (instead of rp&key, now rp&login... and rawurlencode( $user->user_activation_key)...
Now it's the same as before. I can get the username into the url but key is still missing so it's not a problem of the way I get the entries of the database.
